# Formulas in MongoDB views

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to create a MongoDB view which aggregates data inserted in the last 365 days. In my $match stage, before data is massaged, I used the following formula:

```
{
   $match: _created: { $gte: new Date((new Date()).getTime() - (365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) }
}
```

This seemed to work at first but then I noticed that the formula is evaluated prior to creation and the view ends up as

```
{
   $match: _created: { $gte: ISODate('2019-10-17T21:51:10.000Z') }
}
```

which, of course, will not be updated as time passes.

I am using MongoDB Community Server v4.4.1; is there a way to insert the formula itself in the view, not its static result?

Thanks in advance for any helpful comments.

Comment: There is an open request for this feature on MongoDB JIRA; see [User-Parameterized Views](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-10789)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following aggregation pipeline will work with date query to find data within the last year. This pipeline can be used with a view.

```
[ { 
  $match: { 
      $expr: { 
          $gte: [ "$created", { $subtract: [ "$$NOW", 31536000000 ] } ] 
      } 
  } 
} ]
```

The `$$NOW` is the agregation [system variable](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/index.html#system-variables) and its value will be set to the date at the time of running the query on the view.

The value `31536000000` is the `(365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)`.

---

**[EDIT ADD]**

The code I had tried from the `mongo` shell (assuming the collection name is `coll` with the date field `created`).

```
// The aggregation pipeline
> var pipeline = [ { 
    $match: { 
        $expr: { 
            $gte: [ "$created", { $subtract: [ "$$NOW", 31536000000 ] } ] 
        } 
    } 
  } ]

// Create view, using the above pipeline
> db.createView(
    "coll_year_view",
    "coll",
    pipeline
)

// Query the view
> db.coll_year_view.find()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the elegant solution, @prasad_. My environment, however, says the NOW variable is undefined. If you have a chance, do you think you could you be able to shed a light on the problem?

Comment: What is the MongoDB server version you are working with? `NOW` is valid with versions 4.2 or higher. And, I had tried this using `mongo` shell accessing MongoDB v4.2 - works fine.

Comment: I am using MongoDB Community Server v4.4.1. I tried in the Mongo Shell as well and the error message was the same. I also tried it in Compass with the same result. :-/

Comment: I added the code to create the view and use it. NOTE: After you create the view, `show collections` command in the `mongo` shell will list the _view name_ and also the _system.views_.

Comment: It WORKS! Thank you very much, @prasad_. I don't know why my environment did not recognise the system variable but right now that is unimportant. I am just happy my view will work. Again, thanks a million! :)